# Jasmine + Pahtom.js + ReSharper : Test session don't stop after execution

Tags: resharper, jasmine, phantomjs, resharper-7.1

I write my JS tests using Jasmine and execute then with Phantom.js (1.8.1) on ReSharper (7.1)

Everything runs smoothly as ever, exept that the ReSharper Testrunner's Test Session is not stopped after all unittests are run. The result is that everytime I run a new unittest, it opens another Unittests session, and all the other open sessions have the "executing animation".

Any ideas how to get the test session to stop when all tests are run?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem for ReSharper, I've open [a thread](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5476275#5476275) for it.